# How to use ASUS PCE-AX58BT wifi card on ubuntu server 18.04.3 with netplan?

Tags: networking, drivers, asus, iwlwifi

UPDATE:

**The Asus supports final resolution is that the card only runs in PCIe x1 slots and not in x4, x8, x16. That does not make any sense to me but that is what they claim.**

Potentially related bug reports:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204821
- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205123

I returned the wifi card. Before this card I tested another Wifi adapter that also did not work. I gave up on using Wifi on Linux for now. It now costed me 5 months trying to get something to work that should work out of the box.

---

OLD:

I specifically bought a wifi card that has official Linux support, the [ASUS PCE-AX58BT](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/PCE-AX58BT/)

Downloaded the Linux driver (Version 1.0.0.6, 2019/11/12, iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0) from ASUS [here](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/PCE-AX58BT/DR_PCE-AX58BT_v1.0.0.6.zip).
Unziped, mounted the iso, copied the `.ucode` file into `/lib/firmware` as per the [installation instructions of the README](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wHd7mP4BQ6/) and did a reboot.

```
> cp iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode /lib/firmware
> reboot
> lshw -c network

*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:efd00000-efd03fff
```

full output: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/zW4bdn4HMc](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zW4bdn4HMc/)

I don't see a `logical name` for the wifi card so I'm not sure how to configure netplan.

With kernel `5.3.0-24-generic` the output for `dmesg | grep iwl` contained the following points:

```
[    4.172845] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.174215] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.178912] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.3cfab8da.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.187620] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    5.222822] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    5.222900] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.222904] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[    5.222906] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 46.3cfab8da.0
[    5.222908] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL
...
[    5.223000] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.223001] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    5.223012] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
...
[    5.223053] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    5.223056] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
...
[    5.223115] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5f3d, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    5.223117] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    5.223120] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    5.234867] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

full output: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/HxBRpVRzCP](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HxBRpVRzCP/)

I did also test the `iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode` firmware:

```
> wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode
> sudo cp iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode /lib/firmware
> reboot
```

Resulting in the same issue. Full output of `dmesg | grep iwl`: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/5xGhdgcS4d](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5xGhdgcS4d/)

An upgrade to kernel `5.4.10-050410-generic` did not help.
An update of my BIOS to the newest version did not help.

---

I found a very similar issue reported on bugzilla.kernel.org [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204821), where the wifi card is not working in Gen3/x16 and Gen3/x8 PCIe slots but is working in x1/x4 PCIe slots.
I tested my card in a Gen3/x8 and Gen3/x16 slot (with firmware `-46` and `-48` respectively).
I also tested setting the PCIe Gen version to Gen1 and Gen2 in the BIOS (only tested with firmware `-48`).
My board has a Gen2/x4 slot but that one is covered by the CPU cooler and I do not have a small enough cooler to fit anything in that slot.

---

Current state of my system:

- Output for `sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`: no output (file empty)
- Output for `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/S9ngcNRSC2](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S9ngcNRSC2/)
- Output for `grep -i firmware /var/log/syslog* | grep iwl`: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/p4q4CHyVrk](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p4q4CHyVrk/)
- Output for `uname -a`: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/jsYKxg3wg4](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jsYKxg3wg4/)
- Output for `modinfo iwlwifi`: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/PYYb4vG82w](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PYYb4vG82w/)
- Output for `ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi*`: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/wwvSmYJJxJ](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wwvSmYJJxJ/)
- Output for `sudo lspci -vv` (only iwlwifi related): [paste.ubuntu.com/p/b5GCpGHVJC](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b5GCpGHVJC/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103245/discussion-on-question-by-besnep-how-to-use-asus-pce-ax58bt-wifi-card-on-ubuntu).

Comment: I have this same wifi card running on Ubuntu 18.04 with 5.3.0-45-generic. It already has `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode`. No manual configuration needed. Just plug and use. You might want to check this kernel out. Hope this comment can help you.

Comment: The Asus support replied that "ubuntu server" is not supported and that it is not working because of that. They also stated that it should work on ubuntu desktop but I did not yet have the time to confirm / test / redo my server setup. I will update when I do.

Comment: It also does not work on ubuntu desktop.

Comment: The Asus supports final resolution is that the card only runs in PCIe x1 slots and not in x4, x8, x16. That does not make any sense to me but that is what they claim.

Comment: I just got this card running on Funtoo-Linux, sporting a PF kernel ver. 5.1_pf. My motherboard https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DAi.cfm  does not feature a PCIe x1 slot and I have plugged the card in a PCIe x4 slot. It works!

Comment: My board is a ASRock Rack C226M WS: https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=C226M%20WS#Specifications

For now I gave up on the whole Wifi on Linux thing.

Comment: Linux wireless experience is a crap. If you have to use WiFi on linux I recommended to use AP Router + Wire or Intel cards.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried enabling microcode?
https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode

Then installing:
https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Put the ucode files in /lib/firmware/asuswifi/

Reboot

worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).